# How to pass an image from form to another form

Tags: c#, winforms

so i have 2 form and

this what form1 looks like :

[image]

If I click "Browse Image", it will show this:

[image]

heres the code from my first form:

```
private void browseimage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog result = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (result.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
    }
}
```

Inside the `if` I want to store the image file i picked and then pass the value to the second form.

Comment: It's hard to tell how to fix the problem which you have with your code, because you haven't post your code and haven't put any problem details

Comment: Like Sergey wrote, without you placing the code, it will be hard. One way to achieve sending data from one form to another, is to alter the constructor of the form to receive an image, and then have it send when you create an instance of the form.

Comment: You can also make a public property on Form2 which represents the file path to the image, which you can set from Form1 (after you instantiate a Form2 object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the image in an Image type variable and passing the variable by the constructor of your second form. 
Something like this :

```
Image myImage = Image.FromFile("C:\\... 
Pathtotheimage... ");
MyForm form = new MyForm(myImage);
```

On the constructor side of your second form. Do something like this :

```
Public MyForm (Image image) {
//do something here with the image 
}
```

I didn't try to compile this code but you'll have an idea to pass your Image to the second form

Hope it can help

Comment: thank you so much  it worked  :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to create a public property for the image in your Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Image ImageFromForm1 { get; set; }

    // rest of code omitted...
```

Then, when you get the path from the user and create an instance of your form, you can set the property like so:

```
private void browseimage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imageFileTypes = new List<string>
    {
        "Bitmap|*.bmp;*.dib",
        "JPEG|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif",
        "GIF|*.gif",
        "TIFF|*.tif;*.tiff",
        "PNG|*.png",
        "ICO|*.ico",
        "All Images|*.bmp;*.dib;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif;*.gif;*.tif;*.tiff;*.png;*.ico"
    };

    OpenFileDialog result = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures),
        Filter = string.Join("|", imageFileTypes),
        FilterIndex = imageFileTypes.Count
    };

    if (result.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ImageFromForm1 = Image.FromFile(result.FileName);
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```